# How to join two arrays in php

Tags: php, json

I have two arrays called `$array1` and `$array2`

and `var_dump` gives

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=5)
      'userid' => string '8' (length=1)
      'useremail' => string 'venkat@gmail' (length=12)
      'username' => string 'venkatesh' (length=9)
      'password' => string '1111' (length=4)
      'Name' => string 'venkatesh' (length=9)

array (size=1)
  'modenames' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'group 4' (length=7)
      1 => string 'group 4' (length=7)
      2 => string 'group 4' (length=7)
```

now i need to make a json something like this

```
  {
    "userid":"8",
    "useremail":"venkat@gmail",
    "username":"venkatesh",
    "password":"1111",
    "Name":"venkatesh",
    "modenames":{"group 4","group 4","group 4"}
    }
```

i have used array_merge() and $array1+$array2 both gives a json not in above format.. help me out.

Comment: that's because your first array is an array of arrays. you need to `array_merge($first_array[0], $second_array);`

Comment: now i am getting like this `"userid":"8","useremail":"venkat@gmail","username":"venkatesh","password":"1111","Name":"venkatesh","modenames":["group 4","group 4","group 4"]` and how can i replace "[" with "{"?

Comment: `{}` is an object, which requires keys. you cannot have `{"foo"}` as that's totally ambiguous. is it a key, or a value? objects must be `{"key":"value"}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you need to,

```
$t = [
    0 => [
        'userid' => '8',
        'useremail' => 'venkat@gmail',
        'username' => 'venkatesh',
        'password' => '1111',
        'Name' => 'venkatesh'
    ]
];

$s = [
    'modenames' => [
        0 => 'group 4',
        1 => 'group 4',
        2 => 'group 4',
    ]
];

$t = $t[0] + $s;
// or
array_merge($t[0], $s);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sum them like this and encode with `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` flag:

```
$j = json_encode($array1[0]+$array2,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Result:

```
{"userid":8,"useremail":"venkat@gmail","username":"venkatesh","password":"1111","Name":"venkatesh","modenames":{"0":"group4","1":"group4","2":"group4"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$array3 = $array1[0];
$array3['modenames'] = $array2['modenames'];

json_encode($array3);
```

JSON String =

```
{"userid":8,
 "useremail":"venkat@gmail",
 "username":"venkatesh",
 "password":"1111",
 "Name":"venkatesh",
 "modenames":["group 4","group 4","group 4"]
}
```

As an print_r()

```
stdClass Object
(
    [userid] => 8
    [useremail] => venkat@gmail
    [username] => venkatesh
    [password] => 1111
    [Name] => venkatesh
    [modenames] => Array
        (
            [0] => group 4
            [1] => group 4
            [2] => group 4
        )

)
```

Of course your requirement for

```
"modenames":{"group 4","group 4","group 4"}
```

cannot work as you will either need an array occurance as per my example or if you made it an object there would have to be a unique property name one for each of the 3 data items as well as the data.

Answer (score -1):

try with the merge function php. if that is good for you

```
$array3= array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this function doesn't even exist natively.

Comment: that is the official documentation php http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-merge.php

Comment: Right..., look at the name **array_merge**. Plus, the OP already mentioned that doesn't work.